# Parsing html form tags with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I try to parse some sites with html forms.
There is no problem if there is only one opening and one closing form-Tag.
I first realized the Problem by parsing http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

If there are 2 form-tags or more I get a strange behavior, all closing form-Tags are moving to the end of the document. Does anybody have the same problem?

Here is a basic example Webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>HTML Forms and Input</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>stuff and so on</p>
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" size="20"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" size="20">
</form>
<p>some text</p>
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" size="20"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" size="20">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
lSoup = BeautifulSoup(open("forms2.html"))
print lSoup
```

And thats what I got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US"><head>
<title>HTML Forms and Input</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>stuff and so on</p>
<form>
First name: <input name="firstname" size="20" type="text"/><br/>
Last name: <input name="lastname" size="20" type="text"/>
<p>some text</p>
<form>
First name: <input name="firstname" size="20" type="text"/><br/>
Last name: <input name="lastname" size="20" type="text"/>
</form></form></body></html>
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks for help!